# Gmail SPF misconfigured

Tags: email, spf, gmail, google

The [SPF entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) for gmail.com is a redirect to _spf.google.com:

```
$ dig gmail.com txt @8.8.8.8 +short
"v=spf1 redirect=_spf.google.com"
```

_spf.google.com is a redirect to 3 other entries

```
$ dig _spf.google.com txt @8.8.8.8 +short
"v=spf1 include:_netblocks.google.com include:_netblocks2.google.com include:_netblocks3.google.com ~all"
```

_netblocks.google.com contains a list of ipv4:

```
$ dig _netblocks.google.com txt @8.8.8.8 +short
"v=spf1 ip4:64.18.0.0/20 ip4:64.233.160.0/19 ip4:66.102.0.0/20 ip4:66.249.80.0/20 ip4:72.14.192.0/18 ip4:74.125.0.0/16 ip4:173.194.0.0/16 ip4:207.126.144.0/20 ip4:209.85.128.0/17 ip4:216.58.208.0/20 ip4:216.239.32.0/19 ~all"
```

_netblocks2.google.com contains a list of ipv6:

```
$ dig _netblocks2.google.com txt @8.8.8.8 +short
"v=spf1 ip6:2001:4860:4000::/36 ip6:2404:6800:4000::/36 ip6:2607:f8b0:4000::/36 ip6:2800:3f0:4000::/36 ip6:2a00:1450:4000::/36 ip6:2c0f:fb50:4000::/36 ~all"
```

_netblocks3.google.com is an empty record:

```
$ dig _netblocks3.google.com txt @8.8.8.8 +short
"v=spf1 ~all"
```

Why the empty block, is it serving any purpose or just a misconfiguration?

Comment: Perhaps its just there for future usage?

Comment: But doesn't that mean an extra lookup for all the mail servers verifying spf records for gmail messages?

Comment: one idea: mailservers might implement spf checks in a way, that they request netblocks, check if the ip matches, if not they lookup netblocks2, check if it matches if not they check the last one. If this would turn out to be true, google would have an idea of how many mails are sent from ips not allowed by their spf record by looking at the dns statistics for netblocks3. This could be interesting to recognize spammers or a missing ip of their own services.

Answer (score 0):

First things first:

> _spf.google.com is a redirect to 3 other entries

The **include** mechanism is *not* the same as a **redirect**. After evaluating an `include:`, processing returns to the including record, whereas `redirect:` causes the entire process to ignore everything after the redirect in the original record.

As Frederik has already pointed out, `_netblocks3` might be reserved for future use.

When processing SPF validation for messages from legitimate senders, it has *no* effect, since SPF is processed sequentially. The sending MTA would have already matched an `ip4` or `ip6` entry in one of the first blocks and quit validation.

Comment: so this supports my idea from the comment above, they have a third netblock to measure the amount of spam sent from non authenticated servers / or to identify misconfigurations.

Comment: @edlerd that's indead a plausible current use case